# Font identification, similar to Helvetica Condensed

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking for the font used in the word "Honor" from the posters below (click for larger size, image taken from the brilliant designers at Watson from The Jungle Book Social on Behance):
[image: Poster1]

[image: Poster2]

Identifont and WhatTheFont! didn't turn up the right results (note the leg of the R). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The font is "FF Hydra Pro Medium"** form FF Hydra font family.

[image]

All the Best!